# error NG8002: Can't bind to 'datasource' since it isn't a known property of 'table'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, jhipster, angular9

I'm trying to use `mat-table` on angular 9 with angular material 10 but it doesn't work.(And other component as `mat-paginator`...)
It seems that angular doesn't know the material but I already used `@angular/material` in another component.

I already switch `<table mat-table>` to `<mat-table>` but I have angular material 10 and it work with the first one.

I have:

**jh-Material.module.ts** with all the angular materials modules

Who's in **shared.module.ts** (import and export):

```typescript
    @NgModule({
      imports: [KoseCleaningSharedLibsModule,JhMaterialModule],

    exports: [
        JhMaterialModule,
```

Himself in the module.ts for the component.

I tried, without hope, the import of the material in the module for the component.
But when I do that, Ivy isn't happy, I have others errors:

> This likely means that the library `(@angular/material/snack-bar)` which declares `MatSnackBar` has not been processed correctly by `ngcc`, or is not compatible with Angular Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

Weird, because I have another component with angular material and it works.

I also have the imports in the **workers.component.ts**.

I don't have any idea and it takes lot of time without progress...

Thanks you for your help.

Comment: `jh-Material.module.ts` exports all the Angular Material Modules aswell? Or only import? The other component that uses Angular Material, is it in the same module? Have you checked whether the component where you want to make use of it is declared in any module that imports the `JhMaterialModule`?

Comment: Hello, yes, jh-material.module.ts export ans import all the Angular Material modules. The other component isn't in the same module. I checked and the componant are in the JhMaterialModule .

Comment: Maybe try updating your Angular and all dependencies. Make sure to take a backup before doing so! The command for doing so is `ng update -a -f`. This will force update all your npm packages. I've done this several times before and never really got any problems with it. However, maybe I just got lucky.